# Django: template url tag wrong target

Tags: python, django, url

I have in my main urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('scoring.urls', namespace='scoring')),
]
```

and in my app urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'scoring/(?P<query_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_table_data, name='table_api'),
    url(r'^scoring/$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

and in my template:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'scoring:index' %}">Scoring</a></li>
```

but what `{% url 'scoring:index' %}`generates is `localhost/`instead of `localhost/scoring`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you can add the `^scoring` prefix in the main `urls.py` file, instead of writing it everywhere in your scoring urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^scoring/', include('scoring.urls', namespace='scoring')),
]
```

Then in your scoring `urls.py` make sure to add [`app_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs):

```
app_name = 'scoring'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<query_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_table_data, name='table_api'),
]
```

(Note that I removed the `scoring` prefix in the url patterns.)

Now, as you've added `app_name`, the reversing in your template should work as expected.

Comment: I used to have it this way, but changed it to this, because I want to have a `/recent` -site in the same app. Adding app_name didn't resolve it.

Comment: @J.B. Is `scoring` registered in your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?